# Running a custom script alongside systemd in Docker?

Tags: docker

How do you launch a custom script alongside the standard systemd or /sbin/init process inside Docker?

I'm trying to setup a GUI test for a Gnome desktop, and I have a Gnome desktop running perfectly inside Docker. I also have a nice Python script that can click on widgets and verify functionality.

The only limitation is that I have to manually connect to a VNC server running in Docker to connect to the desktop and launch the script. I want to run this in on a CI server automatically, so I can't have any manual steps.

However, I can't find any way to modify my Docker file to run a custom script.

My Dockerfile has a simple `CMD ["/start.sh"]` to launch the main process, which originally was just:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /sbin/init
```

So I tried changing that to:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /sbin/init &
cd /home/default/shared; ./run_tests.py
```

However, the `/sbin/init` line fails with:

```
Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.
```

I'm running my Docker container with:

```
docker run -it --name=my-gnome-desktop --rm \
--tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --tmpfs /tmp \
--cap-add SYS_BOOT --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup \
-v "$(pwd)/testing:/home/default/shared" \
-p 5901:5901 -p 6901:6901 \
my-gnome-desktop-image
```

If I run this with bash, e.g.

```
docker run -it --name=my-gnome-desktop --rm \
--tmpfs /run --tmpfs /run/lock --tmpfs /tmp \
--cap-add SYS_BOOT --cap-add SYS_ADMIN \
-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup \
-v "$(pwd)/testing:/home/default/shared" \
-p 5901:5901 -p 6901:6901 \
my-gnome-desktop-image /bin/bash
```

then I can manually reproduce the behaviors with running `exec /sbin/init` vs `exec /sbin/init &`.

I mount my local `./testing` folder, which contains the test script, as a volume so I don't have to re-build my image every time I tweak my tests. I just kill and re-run the container.

How can I run both `/sbin/init`, which launches the Desktop, and also my test script?

I thought about refactoring my script as a system daemon that starts automatically, but it needs to run as the default user and it needs to run after the X server starts.

Edit:

I tried rewriting my script as a init.d daemon like:

```
cd /home/default/shared
ln -s $(pwd)/run_tests.sh /etc/init.d/
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/run_tests.sh
ln -s /etc/init.d/run_tests.sh /etc/rc2.d/S99run_tests
sudo update-rc.d run_tests.sh defaults
exec /sbin/init
```

But that doesn't work, showing the error:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start run_tests.service.
See 'systemctl status run_tests.service' for details.
```

However, the only additional details `systemctl status run_tests.service` shows is:

```
 Warning: some journal files were not opened due to to insufficient permissions
```

Comment: That sounds like a virtual-machine setup; can you run this in a VM, with a standard desktop Linux installation, and run your initialization as a systemd unit file?  Or, in a full-VM setup, you could run an sshd and use that to launch your tests.

Comment: @DavidMaze In this instance, no, a VM is not appropriate. Many hosted CI systems, where I want to run my tests, don't allow you to run a true VM. And other than this one glitch, Docker's working just fine. It's also a lot faster and consumes much less memory than a full VM.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any simply way to modify `exec /sbin/init` to run a separate process in parallel beside that. However, I did discover that the VNC server I was running was executing an easily modifiable xstartup.sh script.

At the end of that script is:

```
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session
```

which essentially launches the Gnome environment and then blocks. I found that I can launch a separate process in this script by putting something like `nohup my_script.sh &` before this last line.